# Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors and Eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

If there is a symmetric matrix, say

$$B = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 &  A\\
A^T & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

where $A$ is a $m\times n$ submatrix with $m \geq n$.

Is it possible to express the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B$, in terms of singular values and singular vectors of $A$?

(Apologies for the bad formatting)

Answer (score 2):

I assume these are real matrices.
Hint: The condition for $\pmatrix{u\cr v\cr}$ to be an eigenvector of $B$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$ is
$A v = \lambda u$ and $A^T u = \lambda v$.  What does that say about $A^T A v$?